# If $I \subsetneq J$ then $S^{-1}I \subsetneq S^{-1}J$. Is this true?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $I$ and $J$ be two ideals of $A$ with $I \subsetneq J$ then can we claim that $S^{-1}I \subsetneq S^{-1}J$ as $S^{-1}A$ modules?

If the above answer is no. What will happen if we add a few extra conditions that being $S \cap I = \phi$ and $S \cap J =\phi$ ?

I know that the operation $S^{-1}$ is exact. i.e if $\ M'\to M \to M''$ is exact then $S^{-1}M'\to S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}M''$ is also exact.

Now considering $I$ and $J$ as A module and taking the exact sequence $0\to I \to J$ we obtain $S^{-1}I \subseteq S^{-1}J$. But can we tell that the inclusion is proper?

Comment: For a multiplicative subset $S\subset A$ the kernel of $I\to S^{-1} I$ is $\{ i\in I, \exists s\in S,si=0\}$. So you want to find when $J\subset I+ker(S^{-1})$.

Comment: Try the case when $S\cap I\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put this extra information. I have added it to my question.